# Tensorflow GPU installation error, Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install Tensorflow GPU, when executed this command,
`pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`
i get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
__import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
from pip import main
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
  from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
vendored("pkg_resources")
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
__import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I tried reinstalling pip3, am i missing something ?

Comment: Try to `purge` pip3 from your system and install it again.

Comment: check this [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4330)

Comment: `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: 'pip3 install --upgrade setuptools' yields the same error